# Bindingsource error value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: asp.net

[image]I am trying to add BindingSource to my default.aspx.  In properties window, when I click on triangle for datasource, a message box appears saying

Value does not fall within the expected range

Why is that?  How can I set it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is NO `BindingSource` when it comes to ASP.NET You can bind a object directly without BindingSource.

I have seen a lot of questions from you recently, and they all seem to revolve around the same issues. Have you have a look at any asp.net information? http://www.asp.net/web-pages